# HTML table in Lightning using iteration

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, html, table

I have an object 'AccountLineItem' . I have a field 'System' and a boolean field 'isHeader'. I am trying to group by system field where isHeader =true .
I have a Map<String,List> .Which I am returning to my lighningComponent . I am getting a table with correct grouping and records . The issue I am facing is of alignment .

[image]

The way I am using component is

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
      
      <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
            
            <thead>
               <tr class="slds-text-title">
                 <th scope="col" style="width:6.25rem">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap" title="Header1">Action</div>
                    </th>
                    
                    <th scope="col" style="width:6.25rem">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap" title="Header2">GBU</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:6.25rem">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap" title="Header3">PL</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:6.25rem">
                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap" title="Header4">SubPL</div>
                    </th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <tbody>
            
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.mapSystemToAccList}" var="PNumber">
                 
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                       <div class="slds-col">
                    <strong><p>{!PNumber.key}</p></strong>                         
                       </div>
                    
                        
                    </div>
                   <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <th scope="row" style= "width:6.25rem">
                            <lightning:input type="checkbox"  id="{!PNumber.value}" onchange="{!c.selectQuoteLine}" aura:id="boxPackLanguages" />
                        </th>
                    
                        <aura:iteration items="{!PNumber.value}" var="AccLIData" indexVar= "item">
                           <tr>
                            <!--  <div class="slds-grid_vertical slds-gutters_xxx-small">-->
                            <td scope="row" data-label="GBU" style= "width:10.25rem">
                                <div  class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    <ui:outputText value="{!AccIData.Header1__c}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td scope="row" style= "width:6.25rem">
                                <div  class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    <ui:outputText value="{!AccIData.HEader2__c}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td scope="row" style= "width:6.25rem">
                                <div  class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    <ui:outputText value="{!AccIData.Header3__c}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td scope="row" style= "width:6.25rem">
                                <div  class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    <ui:outputText value="{!AccIData.Header4__c}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                           
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration> 
                        
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
                
            </tbody>
            
        </table>
```

Please let me know how can I align records as per header in this scenario

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `<lightning:layout>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing wrong is that you have a `div` in the table flow.

Change this:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
  <div class="slds-col">
     <strong><p>{!PNumber.key}</p></strong>                         
  </div>
</div>
```

To a `<tr colspan="4">`

Once you have a proper table structure, I think the table with work correctly.
Essentially you can't have anything other than `th`, `tbody` or `tr` in your table.... (there may be a couple of other extra obscure tags you can add also)